# Input File isn't being marked as required in React Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, file-upload, material-ui

I have small React form to upload a file. I ask for the file name, a contact email, and the file itself. However, when I do not upload anything to the file input, I am still able to submit the form despite making the input file tag *required*. Why am I still able to submit this form and what can I do to prevent a user from being able to submit the form without uploading a file?

In contrast, when I leave the dataset name or contact email field blank, I am unable to submit because it says "Required"

[image]

For reference, I am using Material-UI for styling.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';
import { TextField } from 'mui-rff';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import { FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
}));

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.datasetName) {
    errors.datasetName = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.contactEmail) {
    errors.contactEmail = 'Required';
  }
  if (!values.uploadFile) {
    errors.uploadFile = 'Required';
  }
  return errors;
};

const UploadForm = () => {
  const classes = useStyles(); 

  const [uploadFile, setUploadFile] = React.useState();

  const onSubmit = async values => {

    const dataArray = new FormData();
    dataArray.append('uploadFile', uploadFile);
  
    console.log('Submitting subscribe form!');
    console.log('Subscribe form values:', values);
  
    axios
      .post("api_url_here", dataArray, {
          headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          }
      })
      .then((response) => {
          console.log('Successfully uploaded file.');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Unsuccessfully uploaded file.');
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        initialValues={{ datasetName: 'dataset.csv', contactEmail: 'johndoe@example.com', uploadFile: 'sample.csv' }}
        validate={validate}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <Grid 
              container
              justify="center"
              alignItems="center"
              spacing={2}>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  label="Dataset Name"
                  name="datasetName"
                  margin="none"
                  required={true}
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  label="Contact Email"
                  name="contactEmail"
                  margin="none"
                  required={true}
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input 
                    name='uploadFile'
                    type='file'
                    required={true}
                    onChange={(e) => setUploadFile(e.target.files)}
                    />
                </FormControl>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={submitting}
                >
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default UploadForm;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the `initialValues` property of the `<Form>` component works but maybe that is the problem. Maybe the input in not empty, maybe its value is the initial value.

Comment: @Titus yes, but the initial value should change when the form itself is changed. It correctly changes for the dataset name and contact email but not for the file upload :(

Comment: I've commented to your previous question about adding `value` properties to the form elements. Did you add one to the `<Input>` component as well ?

Comment: @Titus adding the value property makes it so that the user can't change the form values

Comment: can you not just set ```required``` as an attribute as oppose to ```required={true}```?

Comment: @DavidGrosh yes you are correct, but that is not the issue

Comment: wouldn't the noValidate attribute on the form take away that required check?

Comment: @DavidGrosh no recuasse the validate is on for the surrounding **F**orm (note the capital F)

Comment: @DavidGrosh the dataset name and the email validation works... only the choose file validation does not